# Instant Messenger for Windows in which facebook chat list is available

Tags: windows, chat, facebook

I am looking for a instant messenger that runs on Windows platform. I will tell its specifications :

1. Facebook chat list(list of online friends) should be available on it.
2. It should support all facebook smiley.
3. It should provide different status - online, offline, busy.

I already tried nimbuzz, trillian and instant bird. They all support specification 1, but won't support either 2 or 3.

So can anyone suggest an instant messenger that supports all these specifications ?

Comment: Have you tried Thunderbird? It has a chat messenger that accepts a Facebook account. However, I can't test it for criteria 2 and 3 since I don't have an account

Comment: @Timmy - Thunderbird doesn't support his 2nd requirement.

Comment: You have to distinguish between clients using the XMPP protocol to connect to facebook chat and clients using the Facebook API directly. Since Facebook group chats are not accessible via the XMPP interface there are several differences between those two approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excuse me in advance, I can't comment because I don't have enough points.

[MANI's answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/11499/7459) mentionned [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/) as a possible answer to your requirements.

- It has Facebook integration so you can see online friends discuss with them
- you can manage status as shown below :

  [image: Statuses Pidgin]

On the last point, the vanilla version of pidgin don't have facebook smileys. **BUT**, Pidgin allows [third-party smiley themes](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartySmileyThemes), and you can find a [**theme made by mehdevil**](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Pidgin+Facebook+Smileys?content=162631) which will add all facebook smileys on Pidgin ([picture here](http://gnome-look.org/CONTENT/content-pre1/162631-1.png)).

You just have to download a single file, and the setup of the theme is pretty straightforward :

> To install, just go to "Tools" -> "Preferences" -> "Themes" then drag and drop the file into the "Smiley Theme" section.

Here is an example :

[image]

On the dark side, Pigdin don't have a proper emoji integration. Hope that will not bother you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/download.php) (my best recommendation) because it will support all your needs i.e. Facebook chat list, online status (available, busy, away, listening to, custom message etc), smilies too. May be it won't support Facebook stickers (not sure).
Next alternative is [Pidgin](https://www.pidgin.im/). Its similar to Digsby in all the ways. The only difference is the latter is Open-Source while Digsby is Commercial-freeware software.

Comment: This post does not contain enough information to be considered a high quality answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer, otherwise it might be removed. Especially, an answer should show how the product meets the requirements – and include a link for where to find it. // Edit: Uh, looks like it is us two again, sorry for that...

Comment: Please do. You know, you cannot hide from me *LOL*

Comment: @MANI It can't meet my requirements.

Comment: Did it support FB smilies ?

Comment: Yeah.. I tried it. It doesn't support facebook smilies..

Comment: Now I want to ask what do you exactly mean by smilies? FYI Digsby support more than 20 smilies in chat.